# How to use DSN services in K8s

Tags: angular, spring, kubernetes, kube-dns

I have both an Angular frontend and a backend running on K8s, and I need to apply a NetworkPolicy to the backend pod with the following rule: only allow ingress traffic from your frontend (in the same namespace). The issue at hand is that the front-end's call to reach the backend is done through an URL_ENV (host/path) generated by the backend's Ingress object. In this case, we cannot apply the NetworkPolicy since the communication is not happening pod to pod.

I tried to make to make call using the backend service name and even with the service's DNS.

Comment: Is your angular frontend an static app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels to identify the frontend and backend pods.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-from-frontend
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-app # Label to identify your backend pods
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: frontend-app # Label to identify your frontend pods
```

And then ensure the labels on the pods.

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frontend-app
```

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend-app
```

Note: By using this NetworkPolicy, you're allowing traffic from pods labeled with app: frontend-app to access pods labeled with app: backend-app, regardless of how the frontend's calls are routed (e.g., through Ingress or service DNS).

***It's similar as the AWS Security Group (sg in sg).***

Reference:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Comment: we can not apply networkpolicy when using ingress because the traffic goes out of the cluster

Comment: Are you not managing both the frontend and backend? I'm a bit confused. Could you provide a detailed scenario like frontend A and backend B etc.? This would make it easier for others to assist you with your question.

Comment: the front and the back are in the same namespace but in different deployments, I have an apibaseurl in the front which calls the back, when I call with url of ingress it works but I cannot apply networkpolicy because I leave the cluster , this is not a pod to pod call. I tried to put the apibaseurl http://sevice-backend/ but it doesn't work even though I deactivated CORS-ORIGIN

Comment: I have the same problem but with its solution we cannot apply networkpolicy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096520/angular-pod-intercommunication-with-spring-boot-backend-pod-via-clusterip-servic

Comment: Can you use iptables?